# Can't connect to local database using Visual studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I'm trying to connect to a local database in my project using Visual Studio. I made a local database file and added there some columns.

To get into the database I tried the following code..
(found it on the internet)

```
testcon = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
testcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;" + "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DBtest.mdf;";
testcon.ConnectionString += "database=dBtestDataSet;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Connect Timeout=15";

//open the connection       
testcon.Open();
MessageBox.Show("on");
testcon.Close();
MessageBox.Show("off");
```

The code works for the other people on the internet but I might do something wrong I think..

The following error is that I received.

> SqlExeption was unhandled: An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Image of my code with the solution explorer on the right and the database explorer on the left

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl8oQ.png

I hope someone can help me. I'll be very appreciated.

Comment: What was the values of the `Message` property of the exception?

Comment: (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26)

Comment: Is the name of the database you created the same as the one in your connection string? Did you create your SQL server to allow for integrated security, or must you provide a username and password?

Comment: You are missing \ in "`|DataDirectory|\DBtest.mdf;`"

Comment: @JenishRabadiya it gives me an error in the console..

Comment: @krillgar as far as I know is everything correctly. And there is no password and username needed

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Management Studio Express installed? Are you able to connect to the database with those credentials?

Comment: @krillgar no.. is that program needed for a database inside visual studio? 
I never connected to the database.. so I don't know if I can connect with credentials

Comment: SSMS is a program that allows you to view and query the database directly, outside of Visual Studio. That way you're taking your code out of the equation, and hitting the database correctly. How do you know that you created that database?

Comment: @krillgar I followed on msdn an tutorial for creating a local database (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
try
   { testcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dBtestDataSet;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";

    //open the connection       
    testcon.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("on");
    testcon.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("off"); }
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Debug.Write(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What is exception.Message saying?

Comment: SqlExeption was unhandled: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll   error 26

Comment: there has to be more detail. Changed code to catch exception and write Debug.Write, please send me value of ex.ToString()

Comment: this is what I get when I write the exception. http://pastebin.com/WNJsJy5t @Gaurav

Comment: I only read English. but I see your problem has got a direction above there.